# React: scrollIntoView not working following by dependency of useEffect

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, js-scrollintoview

I have got a dependency `imageNo` in `useEffect()` as I want the element to go up when it's being hidden, but `scrollIntoView()` does not work properly whenever `imageNo` changes, but it works when clicking a `button`.

**Updated**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const Product = ({ product }) => {
  const moveRef = useRef(product.galleryImages.edges.map(() => React.createRef()));
  const [imageNo, setImageNo] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const position = moveRef.current[imageNo]?.current.getBoundingClientRect().y;

    console.log('imageNo', imageNo); // <<<<----- This is also called whenever scrolling excutes.

    if (position > 560) {
      moveRef.current[imageNo]?.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'center',
      });
    }
  }, [imageNo]);

  const test = () => {
    const position = moveRef.current[imageNo]?.current.getBoundingClientRect().y;

    if (position > 560) {
      moveRef.current[imageNo]?.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'center',
      });
    }
  };

  // This changes `imageNo`
  const handleScroll = () => {
    let id = 0;

    console.log('refs.current[id]?.current?.getBoundingClientRect().y', refs.current[id]?.current?.getBoundingClientRect().y);
    const temp = imgArr?.find((el, id) => refs.current[id]?.current?.getBoundingClientRect().y >= 78);

    if (!temp) id = 0;
    else id = temp.id;

    if (refs.current[id]?.current?.getBoundingClientRect().y >= 78) {
      setImageNo(id);
    }
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);


  return (
      <div className="flex flex-row layout-width ">
        {/* aside */}
        <div className="sticky flex self-start top-[76px] overflow-y-auto !min-w-[110px] max-h-[90vh]">
          <div className="">
            {product.galleryImages.edges.map((image, i) => {
              return (
                <div ref={moveRef.current[i]} key={image.node.id}>
                    <Image />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={test}>btn</button>
      </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try without `behavior: 'smooth'`? I suspect that's what's causing the problem. This answer offers a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73297659/330565

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see where the **imageNo** is coming from?
If it is just a normal javascript variable then it wouldn't trigger re-render even after putting it inside the useEffect's dependencies array.
If you want to make the re-render happen based on **imageNo** then make a **useState** variable for **imageNo** and change it using setter function that useState provides.

Helpful note - read about **useState** and **useEffect** hooks in React.

Comment: I have updated my question and added where `imageNo` is coming from. I put `imageNo` inside of `uesState`, but still not rerendered.

Comment: console.log imageNo inside a new useEffect and provide imageNo in its dependency array. And see if imageNo is actually being changed or not. I'm 100% sure that the setter of imageNo is not being called.

Comment: I checked console and `imageNo` is being changed..

Comment: console.log('imageNo', imageNo); // <<<<----- This is also called whenever scrolling executes.

If the above line is called on scroll then this means your useEffect is re-executing.
Then there could be nug in this if (position > 560)  block.
console.log inside this if block and check

Comment: In `if (position > 560)` block, the console also appears..

Comment: moveRef.current[imageNo]?.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'center',
      });

Why do you have current inside current?

Comment: How did you solve this issue? I am also facing this similar issue.